# USB Device Not Recognized Repeated Display

Tags: windows-xp, usb-storage, magicjack

When I launch Windows XP, I keep getting this Warning even though there is NO USB Device Plugged in. 
[image: Who ate my Image?]

A little bit of background information:

We use [Magic Jack](http://www.magicjack.com/6/index.asp) to talk with our friends in the US/Canada. However, of late, we were not able to do Safely Remove Hardware and extract the Device. So, we used to just unplug the device and that also worked pretty well so far.

All of a sudden, the system started coughing up this Warning (and it is quite annoying and distracting). Can you please let me know what is the problem and how to fix it? Thanks!

The System Details are as below:

1. Compaq Desktop Computer
2. Windows XP

Answer (score 2):

I have found the [**Drive Tools for Windows**](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) from [Uwe Sieber's site](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/) very useful for USB related things on the Windows machine.

In this case I'd suggest you check with,

1. **DriveCleanup** - remove nonpresent drives from the registry
2. **ListDosDevices**
3. **DeleteDosDevice**

You may find more things of use for your USB interactions there.

<sup>ps: have you tried clicking through that pop-up to check what can be done?</sup>
<sup>You can also start "Computer Management" by running '`compmgmt.msc`'

and look for devices with problems (red-checks) under Device Manger</sup>

Comment: When I ran Computer Management, I did not see anything with problems (red-checks) under Device Manager. Yes, we did click on that and I cannot remember top of my head what came out of it, but I can assure you that no good came out! I will update it shortly.

Comment: I have just used Drivecleanup. I hope it works. +1.